# Setting static IP to virtual box VM is not working

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

0

I want to assign a static IP to ubuntu 18.04 VM in a virtualbox. I had bridged adopter for adapter 1 and i tried below steps to set static IP,

In the virtual box Host Network Managementt setting, disabled DHCP.
Made Adapter 1 attaching to option as HostOnly Adapter
Started VM and inside VM, opened /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml and made below modifications

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses: [10.110.249.15/24]
      gateway4: 10.110.249.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.110.249.1, 8.8.8.8]
      dhcp4: no
```

My requirement is to access all the hosts in 10.110.249 network and with the above steps i was not able to do that.

How to fix this? Should i just change the adapter 1 setting to bridged adapter and start the VM?

Also in bridged adapter mode, if the host machine where virtual box is installed is accessible to other hosts, will the ubuntu VM also be accessible?

Comment: Did you run `netplan apply` after editing the file?

Comment: @panki: yes, did that